# How to Access PartialView Result in Master Page in mvc3 using razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a method in controller like this

```
public PartialViewResult CabinSearch()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

and I have created a view to this method.

I need to access this partial view to master page

Comment: `  public PartialViewResult CabinSearch()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }`

Answer (score 1):

In Razor, the `@Html.Partial(viewName)` helper will render the named partial view inline in the view. There are other invocations of that to pass a model object to the partial view if it is required.

If you need to invoke the controller method to perform some calculation or database access (as you imply) you can instead use `@Html.Action(actionName, controllerName)` or some variant of that - where CabinSearch is the action name in your case. This will invoke the controller, which will do whatever it does (model preparation) and then render the partial view, which will then be inlined into the page.

Comment: i have used ado.net and all data is in the form of list  
>how to search the list
`  public PartialViewResult GetSearchedResults(string search)  
        {  
           var searched=clsRepository.GetSearchedResults();     
           return PartialView();  
        } `  
>now what code should i write in this controller.